# Magento product save is not working when i add special price in it

Tags: magento-enterprise, products-management, special-price, ee-1.14.2.2

I am working in Magento Enterprise.

When I save a product without any special price, everything is working fine and products are saving from admin.

But when I add a special price, product save is not working. My page does not stop loading when I click save. It is not showing any error and I need to stop Apache to stop loading.

What's wrong with special price?

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: i am using 1.14.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Third-Party Modules**

Disable third-party modules that could possibly be interacting with products.   Go to the `app/etc/modules/` folder and one-by-one set the active node to false within the xml module configuration file, clear cache after each one is disabled, and attempt to save again.

**Modified Core**

If this doesn't work, then you need to check to see if any of the core has been modified.  Check the `app/code/local/Mage` folder to see if any files exist.

Do a diff of the `app/code/core/` directory to an original untouched Magento installation that matches the version you are on.

**Check Browser POST/Response data**

Also, when clicking to update the product, check your AJAX POST/Response.  I use firefox with firebug to do this, but I heard Chrome has an awesome extension that is easy to use.  In firebug, I click the console tab and I can expand GET and POST requests along with the Response.

Comment: Thanks .. I have found a bug its because of third party module. when i off it its working fine

Comment: Got it on first try :)  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities:

- Core admin magento controller for product has been modified.
- There is some module which is overriding admin product controller and it has modified process of saving product.
- There is an observer function which is being called while saving product.

Any of above three possibilities can create problem.

You can also check by enabling magento's log from **`System > Configuration > Advanced (Developer) > Log settings`**. Delete log files from **`/var/log`** folder and re-save product with special price. Now check **/var/log** folder of magento again. There must be some clue now.

Comment: Thanks .. I have found a bug its because of third party module. when i off it its working fine